# centering hyperlinks in HTML (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I believe that I charged significant time today trying to align these hyperlinks to the center of my page with no luck. Please help me as noting works, these are aligned left for some reason I can't understand:

```
/* Custom links*/
.cmenu a { 
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
font-size: 14px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
}
.cmenu a:link { 
color: #0000Ea;
} 
.cmenu a:hover { 
color: #2e8acc; 
}
```

In HTML, I have:

```
<p class="cmenu">
<a href="../home">Home </a>
<a href="../about">About Us</a>
<a href="../forums">Forums</a>
<a href="../contact">Contact</a>
</p>
```

Please note that I tried without having:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

But it didn't work. I appreciate your help.

When I use inspect element I can see:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

If I add the code `text-align:center;` to the above code (last one). I will get them centered. But I can't. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the text-align to the parent element:

```
p.cmenu { * only paragraphs with this class */
  text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
.cmenu { /* any element with this class */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
p.cmenu {
  text-align: center;
}
.cmenu a {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.cmenu a:link {
  color: #0000Ea;
}
.cmenu a:hover {
  color: #2e8acc;
}
```

```html
<p class="cmenu">
  <a href="../home">Home </a>
  <a href="../about">About Us</a>
  <a href="../forums">Forums</a>
  <a href="../contact">Contact</a>
</p>
```

Comment: This will apply it to the whole P in the website, I only want it for those specific selectors. Should I use p.cmenu a {} for all?

Comment: just use p.cmenu or you will apply the style to the a tags again

Comment: What if I was using DIV instead of the P? Shall I use div.cmenu a {} ?

Comment: No...you must apply the text-align to the **parent**

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:center;` will always apply to the children of the container where the style is applied to

```
p.cmenu {
  text-align: center;
}
```

is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

margin auto never center inline-block elements. This only works in block elements. In your case you need apply text-align:center to parent element of your link.